NAudio AsioOut PlaybackStopped and PlaybackState are not working
I am trying to catching the end of the song but I can't. PlaybackStopped is not triggered.
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asioOutDevice = new AsioOut("Focusrite USB ASIO");
        var audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader("music.wav");
        asioOutDevice.ChannelOffset = 1;
        asioOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);
        asioOutDevice.Play();
        asioOutDevice.PlaybackStopped += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped.");
            asioOutDevice.Stop();
        };
        Console.ReadLine();
     }

I checked the PlaybackState but it is always 'Playing'
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(asioOutDevice.PlaybackState);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

I tried PadWithZeroes=false but it didn't work again.
